# How can I get a RESTeasy method to consume application/x-www-form-urlencoded as UTF-8 correctly?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, resteasy

I am using

```
curl --data-binary "content=abcdeöäüabcde" http://myserver.com/application/api -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; encoding=utf-8"
```

to `POST` form data to my web server.

On server side I want to decode the content:

```
@POST
@Path("/api")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void createNote(@FormParam("content") String content){
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

The result is `abcde???abcde`

Does anybody know how I can tell this method to consume the form parameters as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that cURL isn't able to process UTF-8 encoded Strings in POST requests at all. Converting the string to `latin1` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
byte[] encoded = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: I just did. The resulting hex codes are: `61 62 63 64 65 c3 83 c2 b6 c3 83 c2 a4 c3 83 c2 bc 61 62 63 64 65` - This doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: encoded.toString() returns the Object-id or address of the array. But I tried new String(encoded, "UTF-8"). Didn't work either.